# Cocos2d animated app intro

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

Is there any way to create animated app intro in cocos2d instead use of static Default.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. The very first screen can not be animated.

Answer (score 0):

Splash screen will surely come in to picture.
I think you can do 1 thing.... Just create a scene with same background as Default.png.
As soon as Splash screen is there.. your background is visible and when your Intro scene is called, show your animated intro. This won't look as 2 different screens. After the intro is complete, switch your scene to Menu Scene or whatever.